# Como encontrar numa tabela a categoria com o mínimo de observações?

Tags: r

Suponha que tenha os seguintes dados:

```
a<-c(rep("agosto",3),rep("janeiro",4),rep("maio",6))
table(a)
```

Quero saber qual o mês com o mínimo de observações?

Com a função `min(table(a))` a resposta é o valor mínimo e não o mês com menos observações.

Se usar a função `which.min()` tem-se o seguinte resultado.

```
> which.min(table(a))
agosto 
     1
```

Mas o que preciso é que retorne apenas a categoria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode pegar somente o atributo `names` do `which.min`:

```
a<-c(rep("agosto",3),rep("janeiro",4),rep("maio",6))
tabela<-table(a)
names(which.min(tabela))
[1] "agosto"
```

Para entender melhor, quando você coloca `which.min(tabela)` você gera um vetor com um atributo de nomes:

```
str(which.min(tabela))
 Named int 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "agosto"
```

Então se você quiser pegar somente o(s) nome(s) do vetor, você usa a função `names`.  Uma outra forma de fazer a mesma coisa é `attr(which.min(tabela), "names")`